# Help with my SQL Query

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, cloud

Hello all I am trying to get timestamps from today and yesterday.  The thing is my query is only returning rows for today - am I missing something?  I normally dont use multiple conditions in a JOIN statement but my logic seems like it makes sense

I am using dateadd to minus 1 day but its still returning only aug 8 entries - see screenshot as well

```
SELECT O.subscriber_key, O.timestamp, O.data from  abandoned_browse_1643376986  O
JOIN ENT._Subscribers s ON O.subscriber_key = s.SubscriberKey
AND  
(
cast(O.timestamp As Date) = cast(GetDate() As Date)     
OR 
cast(DATEADD(day,-1,O.timestamp )As Date) = 
cast(DATEADD(day,-1, GetDate())  as DATE)
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try something like the following, using the `WHERE` clause ?

```
SELECT O.subscriber_key, O.timestamp, O.data
FROM abandoned_browse_1643376986 O
JOIN ENT._Subscribers S ON O.subscriber_key = S.SubscriberKey
WHERE 
    DATEDIFF(DAY, O.timestamp, GETDATE()) = 0
OR
    DATEDIFF(DAY, O.timestamp, GETDATE()) = 1
```

Orig DE :

[image: Orig DE]

Filtered DE with only today's and yesterday's records :

[image: Filtered DE]

Comment: THanks - your query seems to look good.  I actually wrote the below it returned more than double your query - both seem to have the same logic, have any idea why? 


SELECT DISTINCT O.subscriber_key, O.timestamp, O.data from  abandoned_browse_1643376986  O
JOIN ENT._Subscribers s ON O.subscriber_key = s.SubscriberKey
WHERE
cast(O.timestamp As Date) >=  cast(DATEADD(day,-1,getdate() )As Date)

Comment: Do you get timestamps from today and yesterday now ?

Comment: Only today which is weird (for my query)

Comment: @GS65 : Made some enhancements and added a test result : you should be good to go with this one. Also, you may not actually need a join on All Subscribers, except maybe to insert only existing subscribers.

Comment: THanks for the help I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I generally select rows from yesterday:

```sql
SELECT 
  O.subscriber_key
, O.timestamp
, O.data 
from abandoned_browse_1643376986 O
JOIN ENT._Subscribers s ON O.subscriber_key = s.SubscriberKey
where 
o.timestamp >= convert(date, getDate()-1)
and o.timestamp < convert(date, getDate())
```

Convert is native to SQLServer and is allegedly faster.  When converting to a `date` you're effectively resetting the time part of the timestamp to midnight.  So the translation of my example above would be:

> select rows after yesterday at midnight and include anything before midnight today

Using [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) where-clauses is a good thing performance-wise.